# How to fix git push or pull problem SSL_CTX_set_alpn_protos

Tags: git

I am using a sheared hosting , and i access this host using ssh 
everything was working just fine

but suddenly when i try to push or pull i get this error

```
/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/libexec/git-core/git-remote-https: 

relocation error: /usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4: symbol SSL_CTX_set_alpn_protos, version libssl.so.10 not defined in file libssl.so.10 with link time reference
```

so any idea for how to fix it

Comment: Looks like a library or application was upgraded a version is now referenced which does not exist on your system. Roll back updates or update everything.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 0):

cPanel ships a version of Git under `/usr/local/cpanel`, which is what you're using.  This version of Git uses OpenSSL and libcurl.

For some reason, the version of OpenSSL you're using is broken.  That could either be because your hosting provider is using a really old version of CentOS 7 which is no longer supported, or it could be because they're replaced the system OpenSSL on their system with another version, which is a uniformly bad idea.

Either way, this is a defect with your hosting provider and you should report it to them.  If they don't fix it promptly or if they give you the run around, you should move to a different hosting provider.  There is nothing you can do in a shared hosting environment to fix this, since you will not have the root privileges required to reinstall the system OpenSSL or upgrade the system.